# Nested (non model) Serializer in a ModelSerializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a fairly niche use case that I'm trying to use DRF serializers for.  It will be hard to explain precisely what I'm doing, or why I'm doing it, but I need it to work like this.

I have a ModelSerializer, that has nested in it, a regular Serializer, and another ModelSerializer.  Something like this:

```
class ASerializer(Serializer):
     ...some fields

class BSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Foo
         fields = '__all__'

class CSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     a = ASerializer()
     b = BSerializer(source='*')
     class Meta:
         model = Foo
         fields = ('a', ' b')
```

I want to use it like this:

```
s = CSerializer(foo_instance, data={'a': ...some data})
s.is_valid()  # if necessary
out_data = s.data
```

Expecting:

```
out_data = {'a': ...some manipulated data, 'b': ...the serialized foo instance}
```

So I want to have a serializer, that I pass an instance of Foo to, and some data.  The instance of foo is simply to be passed to the nested ModelSerializer (BSerializer) to serialize back out (in a very specific way), and the data I pass is just for the nested Serializer (ASerializer) for that to do some logic (possibly validation) on, and send back out.  I'm not using this to modify the model instance in any way, at no point will I call save/create/whatever.  It's basically just a data transformation leveraging DRF serializers.

The issue I have is that after initialization, and validation (which does pass!) I get the error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `a` on serializer `CSerializer` ... Original exception text was: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I also appreciate that the following works without error:

```
x = ASerializer(data=...some data)
x.is_valid()
y = BSerializer(foo_instance)
out_data = {'a': x.data, 'b': y.data}
```

But it seems like my desired interface, combining these steps by a single serializer, should be possible - but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different arguments, the `instance` and the `data` arguments. The `instance` argument is used to pass in the object that needs to be **serialized** into native datatypes, whereas the `data` argument takes in native datatypes that need to be **deserialized**.

What you can do to get your desired interface is to add the relevant data onto your instance before passing it to the serializer:

```py
# Add your data as an attribute to your instance
foo_instance.a = some_data
s = CSerializer(foo_instance)
s.is_valid()
out_data = s.data
```

Considering that you have two different values that you want your serializer to take in perhaps a better option would be to forego the `source='*'`:

```
# Why does this even need to be a ModelSerializer? Why not Serializer instead?
class CSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     a = ASerializer()
     b = BSerializer()
     class Meta:
         model = Foo
         fields = ('a', ' b')
```

And then use it like below by passing a dictionary to it:

```
s = CSerializer({'a': some_data, 'b': foo_instance})
s.is_valid()
out_data = s.data
```

Comment: Using both instance and data arguments is not bad, or even unusual.  This is what you would do if you wanted to update an existing "instance" with  new "data" - indeed this is precisely what the UpdateModelMixin in the rest_framework code does.  But regardless, unfortunately this solution doesn't work.  The BSerializer complains that it was expecting a dict, but got a Foo instance.  I potentially could use foo_instance.__dict__, but not only is this ugly, there's the potential for validation errors with the serializer thinking I'm trying to create a duplicate instance.

Comment: @DavidDownes Why would `BSerializer` complain about getting a `Foo` instance? It is a `ModelSerializer`. Also `serializer.data` is not used to access _updated_ data, it is used to access the _serialized_ data and the serialized data completely depends on the `instance`.

Comment: I presume because data is a parameter designed to be a dict of data to populate fields, not instances of models to populate nested serializers.  If you don't believe me, feel free to try the code out - you can copy/paste it and try it any model of any app you have running.

Comment: @DavidDownes we aren't passing `data` anywhere in my code though? Also I have tested both of the solutions I present and they work on my side. You are probably lacking an [mre] here.

Comment: Ah, I misread that, I thought it was to pass the dict (containing the instance) in as the data - apologies.  So this does work, except that you can't call is_valid() on the serializer, since you aren't passing in a data argument.  This is annoying since I do want to validate the data in the ASerializer, but it does at least allow me to get out the data I pass, along with the serialized model instance.  It's 50/50 is that's an improvement over the original solution in the question :-/

Comment: @DavidDownes you can still pass `data` to the serializer (Must be similar to what we pass in instance but just the opposite direction), you will have to implement the create / update method yourself though since DRF does not support nested relations out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, how can I pass data and the instance? It always leads me to an error.  Either it complains that 'b' is missing from the data and is required, or that 'a' is not a field on the Foo model, or some other similar thing.  If you could provide a complete suggested solution, I'm more than happy to award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work:

```
foo_instance.a = ...some data
s = CSerializer(foo_instance)
out_data = s.data
```

I'm not certain if adding `.a` property to `foo_instance` will give any side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I was exposed on same kind of problem on last project.

The way I found is:

```py
# getting object from database :
instance         = MyModel.object.filter(pk = pk)
# changing it value
instance.value   = "my new value" # From request or wathever
# then run into serializer to convert into JSON data
model_to_json    = MyChildSerializer(instance)
# then run again into serializer to validate new data
serializer       = MyChildSerializer(model_to_json.data, context = {"account" : request.user})
if serializer.is_valid() :
    ...
```

When serializer run, depending of the source type some function will run and some other not. For exemple the function `to_internal_value` value will be call only during unserialize process.

**Parent serializer**

```py
class MySerializer(
    serializers.ModelSerializer,
    ) :

    '''
    This serializer should only be called by Serializer
    '''
    class UrlSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :

        class Meta :
            model   = links_models.Url
            fields  = ['slug', 'code']

    duration    = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    source      = UrlSerializer(read_only = False)

    target      = UrlSerializer(read_only = False)

    '''
    This function is only called during UNSERIALIZE process
    '''
    def to_internal_value(self, data) :
        _data       = OrderedDict()
        duration    = OrderedDict({'duration'   : data['duration']})

        _data.update(duration)
        _data.update(super().to_internal_value(data))
        return _data

    '''
    This function is called during SERIALIZE and UNSERIALIZE process
    '''
    def get_duration(self, object) :
        if isinstance(object, OrderedDict) : # is it unserialize or serialize process?
            return object.pop('duration')
        else :
            MONTH   = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4
            WEEK    = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
            week    = int((int(object.duration) % MONTH))
            month   = int(object.duration) - int(week)

            week  = int(week / WEEK if week > 0 else 0)
            month = int(month / MONTH if month > 0 else 0)
            return {"month" : month, "week"  : week}

    class Meta :
        model = MyModel
        field = ['duration', 'source', 'target']
```

**Child Serializer**

```py
class MyChildSerializer(MySerializer) :

    '''
    By default read_only is True.
    '''
    state       = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    '''
    This function is only called during UNSERIALIZE process
    '''
    def to_internal_value(self, data) :
        _data       = OrderedDict()
        state       = OrderedDict({'state'      : data['state']})

        _data.update(state)
        _data.update(super().to_internal_value(data))
        return _data

    '''
    This function is called during SERIALIZE and UNSERIALIZE process
    '''
    def get_state(self, object) :
        if isinstance(object, OrderedDict) :  # is it unserialize or serialize process?
            return object.pop('state')
        else :
            state = object.state

            state = LeaseStateSerializer(
                    state,
                    read_only  = True,
                    )
        return state.data

    def validate_state(self, value) :
        if not value == =MyModel.WAIT :
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'state' : _("An error occure; action not permited")}
                )
        return value

    '''
    This function is only called during UNSERIALIZE process
    '''
    def validate(self, data) :
        if not self.context.get("account") :
            raise Exception("Account is require in context when submiting " \
            "validation on %s" % (MyChildSerializer.__name__)
            )
        validate = super().validate(data)
        self.validate_state(validate.get('state'))
        return (validate)

    class Meta :
        model = MyModel
        field = ['duration', 'source', 'target', 'state']
```